# Need small and light stand-alone one-file ftpd server

Tags: ftp, remote, file-copy

Can somebody suggest a small one-.c-file ftpd server, so I can run it on any port and it would accept ftp upload with any l/p on that port and put a file into a folder where it runs?

No config files and so on, just a mere command line options.

PS Would be good if the code is not from 90x.

Comment: Does it have to be FTP, or are you just trying to accept files from anywhere?  Asking because it might affect the answer - also how much support do you need for different users.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comment, I would use [netcat](http://nc110.sourceforge.net/) and not bother with FTP at all (assuming you can't use scp).

Source server,

```
cat myfile | nc -q 10 -l -p <someport>
```

Target server,

```
nc sourceserver someport > targetfile
```

If you still think you need an FTP server (and your question still doesn't say why it must support FTP), then you can look through the ones on this list,

[Wikipedia List of FTP Server Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_software)

To be honest, not sure how you handle running it on non-standard ports, FTP uses two ports (21 and 22), one for data and one for commands.  You can alter the behaviour using passive FTP, but I've never tried to set up an FTP server outside of the typical ports (because FTP is generally insecure).

I think you need to look at scp (not sure why you can't use it, you don't stipulate).

Comment: Not sure why it's less reliable than FTP, anyway, you might want to update your question to include the size of the files, frequency, etc.

Comment: @user9456 it's actually extremely reliable for large files.

Comment: You may even want to hack together an `xinetd` setup for the `netcat`...